# all combinations of items in a list. all containing alle items

Tags: python, list, combinations

looking for an easy way to get all combinations
input: list of strings

```
list = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
```

output: nested list of strings

```
[["abcd"],["abc", "d"],["ab","cd"],["a","bcd"],["ab","c","d"],["a","bc","d"],["a","b","cd"],["a","b","c","d"]]
```

Comment: What have you tried, and what exactly is the problem with it?

Comment: Take a look at [itertools](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html).

Comment: This is the partitions problem which has many answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use recursion with a generator:

```
def combo(d):
  yield d
  if len(d) > 1:
    for i in range(len(d)-1):
       yield from combo([*d[:i], d[i]+d[i+1], *d[i+2:]])

print(list(set(map(tuple, combo(["a", "b", "c", "d"])))))
```

Output:

```
[('a', 'b', 'c', 'd'), ('abcd',), ('ab', 'c', 'd'), ('abc', 'd'), ('a', 'b', 'cd'), ('ab', 'cd'), ('a', 'bcd'), ('a', 'bc', 'd')]
```